# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' when hosting a Discord bot on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm, discord

i wanted to host a discord bot that i created (with Node.js) on Heroku but is throwing that error:

```
2021-11-05T00:00:10.334347+00:00 app[web.1]: > node .
2021-11-05T00:00:10.334348+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393407+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393408+00:00 app[web.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393409+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^^^
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393409+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393409+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393412+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393413+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393413+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393413+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393414+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393414+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393414+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393415+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:4:20)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393415+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.393415+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-11-05T00:00:10.400407+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-11-05T00:00:10.400581+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-11-05T00:00:10.403958+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! discord-bot@1.0.0 start: `node .`
2021-11-05T00:00:10.403998+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-11-05T00:00:10.404053+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-11-05T00:00:10.404092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the discord-bot@1.0.0 start script.
2021-11-05T00:00:10.404140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-11-05T00:00:10.408367+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-11-05T00:00:10.408447+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-11-05T00:00:10.408486+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-11-05T00_00_10_404Z-debug.log
2021-11-05T00:00:10.592782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-11-05T00:00:10.917668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

this is my package.json:

```
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "discord.js": "^13.3.1",
    "discord.js-commando": "^0.12.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

i added a procfile too : `worker: node src/index.js`

**i have the Node.js latest version (16.0)**

what should i do to fix that error?

Comment: hi, could there be some stray unicode chars in the source? perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516153/syntax-error-unexpected-token-discord-bot-coding

Comment: Instead of `x ??= y`, try using `x ?? (x = y)` The nullish assignment is relatively new, but should be available as of Node 15.0. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment#browser_compatibility

Comment: @jspcal probably that is not the problem :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update node to >= v16.6.0.

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/5119

Comment: will this work if i update to 17.0.1 instead?

Comment: Yes, 17.0.1 > 16.6.0.

Comment: i did that and update discord.js, the error is fixed, thanks!

Comment: @MatheusChiarelli remember to mark answers that help you so others that have a similar problem can find answers more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

i just update discord.js to version 12.5.3 and worked! i appreciate all the answers

Comment: Thank you for following up with the solution!

Answer (score -2):

For me that looks like you don't passed a token.

If you getting the token out of an file, please make sure it gets readed correctly.

Comment: the error is not about the Discord Token.

Comment: i passed, is reading correctly